# How to dynamically change the playback rate of video in iOS?

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, avfoundation, playback

The perfect example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen in the [Flow ● Slow and Fast Motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXc7ym2guu4) app .

One can change the playback rate of the video by **dragging** points on the curve up or down. The video can also be **saved** in this state.

I am looking for a way to dynamically  speed up/down  a video  , so that the playback rate can be changed while the video is being played.

[Video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXc7ym2guu4)

[image]

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- The playback `rate` property of `AVPlayer` .But it Only works with a few values for playback Rate(0.50, 0.67, 0.80, 1.0, 1.25, 1.50, and 2.0 ) and one cannot save the video
- The `scaleTimeRange(..)` property of `AVMutableComposition`. But it doesn't work when you want to **ramp** the video for gradually decreasing slow/fast motion.
- **Display video frames** on screen using `CAEAGLLayer` and `CADisplayLink`. But my many attempts on trying to achieve Slow/Fast motion with this have been unsuccessful .

All this has taken me months and I'm starting to doubt if I'll be able to accomplish this at all.

Thus any suggestion , would be immensely valuable.

Answer (score 2):

In IOS, the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` object contains a 'nowPlayingInfo' dictionary whose contents describe the item being played. It is advised that you start the playback at the 'currentplaybackrate' and then set the speed. See this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16739) on the developer's forum.

You might possibly end up with something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/611foa9e/) (but this is javascript) where the playback rate of the video has been sped up by 4.

```js
  document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 4.0;
  document.querySelector('video').play();
```

```css
video{width:400px;
   height:auto;}
```

```html
<video controls preload="true" autoplay>
      <source src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/nature.mp4" type="video/mp4" > 
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I will experiment with the `MediaPlayer` framework once I fail to find anything helpful in `AVFoundation` because I still think the _easing slow motion_  problem can be solved with it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/nL9zoezm/ slowed down version, doesn't seem to have sound under 0.5 playback rate (or maybe i just didn't listen long enough..)

Comment: Although a high range of integer value for the `playackRate` can be used in JavaScript , I don't know if there is a way to export the video with that `playbackRate` .

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/UsingAVKitPlatformFeatures/UsingAVKitPlatformFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH5-SW4   refer to Create a CMTimeRange (16th instance of 'time' using Find.. , and how to export the said media time-range (down the end of the page)

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure I fully understand the use case you're going for, but I think

```
func setRate(_ rate: Float, 
      time itemTime: CMTime, 
      atHostTime hostClockTime: CMTime)
```

[[Apple Documentation Source]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1386591-setrate)

Is something that you're looking for. While this may not be exactly what you need, I'm also not sure where in the docs there is exactly what you're looking for, but with the above method alone, you could do the following to save videos at a variable rate:

1. Use the above method to play the video throughout (assuming it's not too long, otherwise this will be computationally impossible/timeout-worthy on some devices) at the desired rates each second. Design UI to adjust this per second rate.
2. under the hood you can actually play the video at that speed "frame by frame" and capture the frames you want (in the right # which will give you the rate you desire) and voila -- saving the right number of frames together (skipping/duplicating as needed to increase/lower desired rate based on "picker" UI) you've now accomplished what you desire

To be clear, what I'm talking about here is a video output @ 60FPS has 60 frames per second. You would literally "cut and paste" frames together from the source video into the "destination" video based on whatever UI steppers values you receive from your user (in the screenshot-ed example the question contains, as my basis), and pick up that many frames. AKA if the user says seconds 2-10 of their 20 second video should be at 2X, only put in 30 frames for each of those seconds (if filmed at 60 FPS) alternating frames. The output will, at 60FPS, seem like 2X speed (since there are now 30 frames per 1 second of original video, which is 0.5 seconds at 60 FPS). Similarly, any value can appropriately be factored into:

- (desired consistent FPS) = (source video FPS) = (destination video FPS) *(ie 60 or 90)*
- (rate) = (rate from UI steppers/graph UI to pick rate @ each time interval) *(ie 1X/2x/0.25X)*
- (desired consistent FPS)  * (rate)  = (# frames kept in destination video)
- (destination video frames) = (source video) * (desired consistent FPS) ~modulated by~ (per *custom time interval* rate)

The exact mechanisms for ^^ might actually be built into AVPlayer and I didn't find the details, but this alone should be a good start to get you going in that direction.

Comment: Great answer. I am not  quite sure about  the `setRate(..)` property works , but I shall get back as soon as have a working example . Meanwhile I've been trying to explore other ways of doing this , and also build the UI for the player.
Thank you for the response ,  you're great!

Comment: Yea, to be honest I'm not even sure you need setRate, depending the type of video. You could probably use AVPlayer to grab individual frames and then collate them accordingly based on the desired final rate at each time chunk modified by the user. @Tyrone but the apple documentation for AVPlayer (found at the `setRate` docs in my answer) should lead you to how to do that as well.